# what factors would you use to rank the importance of use case scenarios as they relate to a cost-benefit ratio?

Tags: use-cases

**Examples:**

- Users (# of)
- Frequency of Action (# per XYZ)
- Cost (Resource XYZ)
- Usability Problems (Hard <> Easy)
- Failure Rate (successful <> unsuccessful)

And based on the factors you present, **what would be the formula for doing an evaluation?**

Comment: Your question is very abstract, could you try to make it more concrete?

Comment: **@Rahul:** It is an abstract question, and the answer should be able to be applied universally to all use case scenarios cost-benefit analysis.

Comment: the point is that this site is NOT a site for abstract questions. The purpose of this site is to ask questions that can have specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Number of users * Frequency of use * Value of successful transaction)/Development_Cost, where value of transaction could be a number of things, but most common is monetary value.

I don't think most UX folks would tell you that you can infer usability, success, or failure from a use case, as a use case is used to inform a functional requirement, not aesthetics or style, which should not be downplayed when discussing usability of an inteface.

Comment: +1 So, how do you rate the values the user places on the transaction, verse the value the business does?

Comment: That kind of value can be subjective.  For instance if the user was involved in the creation of the thing they're transacting on, they value it higher than if they didn't have any input into it's creation.

Comment: FYI this is how comments work. Yes, it's silly, but how SE's system works -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work (meaning that unless you but "@blunders:" I will not see you replied

Comment: Sort of, in some cases though it's more of a matter of conflicting interest, which is more what I was thinking about. Meaning that the value produced to the user is high, but the cost to the business is high as well. Vendor lock-in would be a perfect example of this. REFERENCE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in

Comment: @blunders: That's just business and product development... that's when you have to weigh the speed of progress against your cost and the purpose of your business.  If an organization came along today that did what you're hesitant to do without the costs you have, your users may abandon you.  So you have to decide, are you going to create opportunities out of the problems you face or let someone else do it for you.